# Having issues with Apache Tomcat log

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, netbeans

i accidently clicked on x and closed my apache tomcat log where i can see all the exceptions netBeans throws and i am having a big problem finding on internet how to enable it again. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

go to services tab/window, open servers and right click on the server you want. Then click 'View Domain Server Log'